# Why does this Swing border get painted when starting the application from the console but not when executing via double click?

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton

I have a Java Swing application which contains a JCombobox with a custom editor.
The editor contains a JButton which can be used to add an entry to the combobox.

The application is built using Apache Maven.

I have encountered some strange behaviour from said button, namely that its border, which I added manually, gets painted when running the application in Eclipse or on the console via `java -jar application.jar` but not when double clicking the jar file.

[image: Started from console or Eclipse]

[image: Started via double click]

Executing `java -version` on the console returns `1.8.0_121`.

My `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`.

Eclipse has the same as the only entry under *Installed JREs*.

The java version in my *pom.xml* is also 1.8.

Below is the code of my custom editor class.
The border is added in the constructor.

```
public class ButtonComboBoxEditor implements ComboBoxEditor {

private JLabel label;
private JButton button;
private JPanel panel;
private Object selectedItem;

public ButtonComboBoxEditor() {
    panel = new JPanel();

    label = new JLabel();
    setConnected(false);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 0));

    button = new JButton();
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(18, 14));
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 1, 0, 1, new Color(202, 202, 202)));
    button.setBorderPainted(true);
    button.setToolTipText("Add connection");

    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
}

public ButtonComboBoxEditor(Icon buttonIcon, ActionListener l, ComboboxToggleListener toggleListener) {
    this();
    setButtonIcon(buttonIcon);
    addButtonActionListener(l);
    addMouseListener(toggleListener);
}

public ButtonComboBoxEditor(String buttonText, ActionListener l, ComboboxToggleListener toggleListener) {
    this();
    button.setText(buttonText);
    addButtonActionListener(l);
    addMouseListener(toggleListener);
}

private void addMouseListener(ComboboxToggleListener toggleListener) {
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
            toggleListener.editorPressed();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Component getEditorComponent() {
    return panel;
}

@Override
public void setItem(Object anObject) {
    selectedItem = anObject;
    label.setText(anObject.toString());
}

@Override
public Object getItem() {
    return selectedItem;
}

@Override
public void selectAll() {
}

@Override
public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
}

@Override
public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {
}

public void setButtonIcon(Icon icon) {
    button.setIcon(icon);
}

public void addButtonActionListener(ActionListener l) {
    button.addActionListener(l);
}

public void removeButtonActionListener(ActionListener l) {
    button.removeActionListener(l);
}

public void setConnected(boolean connected) {
    if (connected) {
        label.setBackground(new Color(130, 220, 130)); // Green
    } else {
        label.setBackground(new Color(220, 130, 130)); // Red
    }
}
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Cheers.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like the problem is not the button but rather the JCombobox itself.
I fixed the problem for now by adding a border to the combobox.

I would still be interested in what causes the differences of the layout.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Which java version is registered for double click?

Comment: Double click also uses the jdk 1.8_121